# How can I check if a player moves onto a box with the letter "P" inside...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game for class and I have done almost everything except I need to check whether the player moves over a passenger and if so, display an alert box. Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ8vA/7/. As you can see I have an array called `map` which is what is used to construct the grid, and then later check what colour the user is on, however I need to check whether they also go over a "P", represented by the letter "P" in the grid. I have by default added `map2` however that doesn't do anything, I was trying to make a second map array to store the passengers and the base but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

How can I check to see whether the user goes over a box with the letter "P" and if so display an alert? I have created a function to check for the letter "P" however I created this when I used "p" in the `map` array, however that removed the colours which is not what I intended (I still need the colours, hence the idea of a second array)).

```
function checkPass(cell, row) {
    var pass = map[row][cell];
    console.log(pass);
    if (pass == "p") {
    alert("Passenger");
      }
    }
```

How can I do this?(code examples will be helpful (or in the fiddle)

EDIT:

In my fiddle under the map array I use the letter "P" instead of "g", "b" or "w" in some of the lines. This was how I know it works but in the fiddle it replaces the colour checking for the P. I need a way to check if they are on a P, but keep the colours, so hence why I need help with a second map array to store the passengers and base (or another suitable alternative).

Comment: I just tried your fiddle, and it works correctly? Unless I am missing the question... EDIT: It seems it only works for the first P cell.

Comment: In my fiddle under the `map` array I use the letter "P" instead of "g", "b" or "w" in some of the lines. This was how I know it works but in the fiddle it replaces the colour checking for the P. I need a way to check if they are on a P, but keep the colours, so hence why I need help with a second map array to store the passengers and base (or another suitable alternative).

Comment: You might consider creating an object and storing that in your array instead of multiple arrays.  The object could contain whatever information is needed, the color, the letter, etc.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? (sorry still learning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your array of letters with a 2d array of objects.  Something like this:

```
var map = [
            [
                {
                    color: "g",
                    letter: "p"
                },
                {
                    color: "g",
                    letter: ""
                },
            ],[
                {
                    color: "w",
                    letter: "p"
                },
                {
                    color: "b",
                    letter: ""
                }
            ]];
```

This would represent a 2x2 "map".

Then your code to check the passenger would be like this:

```
function checkPass(cell, row) {
    var pass = map[row][cell].letter;
    console.log(pass);
    if (pass == "p") {
        alert("Passenger");
    }
}
```

And your existing code which utilized the letters for colors would be something like this:

```
var color = map[row][cell].color;

$('#grid .box:eq(' + count + ')').addClass(class_color[color]);
```

Comment: In reality, you should probably replace your hardcoded letters with variables in some way.  Maybe a pseudo-Enum, but I don't want to throw too much at you at once.

Comment: @user3481788 You haven't changed any of the places where the values are used.

Comment: My bad. I got it working although shouldn't it pick up the "P" in the white from what I used here: http://jsfiddle.net/nZ8vA/9/? It seems to pick it up at the bottom of the grid though???